# How to access class method from the included hook of a Ruby module

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming

I'd like my module to define new instance methods based on its including class' instance methods. But in the `included` hook, the class methods are not defined yet (as the module is included at the top of the class, before the class methods are defined):

```rb
module MyModule
    def self.included(includer)
        puts includer.instance_methods.include? :my_class_method # false <- Problem
    end
end

class MyClass
    include MyModule
    def my_class_method
    end
end
```

I want the users of the module to be free to include it at the top of their class.

Is there a way to make a module define additional methods to a class?

Note: I don't have to use the `included` hook if there is another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There'a a [`method_added`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Module.html#method_added-method) callback you could use:

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(includer)
    def includer.method_added(name)
      puts "Method added #{name.inspect}"
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyModule

  def foo ; end
end
```

Output:

```
Method added :foo
```

If you want to track both, existing and future methods, you might need something like this:

```
module MyModule
  def self.on_method(name)
    puts "Method #{name.inspect}"
  end

  def self.included(includer)
    includer.instance_methods(false).each do |name|
      on_method(name)
    end

    def includer.method_added(name)
      MyModule.on_method(name)
    end
  end
end
```

Example:

```
class MyClass
  def foo ; end

  include MyModule

  def bar; end
end

# Method :foo
# Method :bar
```